# Unit test angular 4 directive having @input property

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular2-directives

I have a directive `AllowOnlyNumbers` which applied to input type textbox.

```
<input                         
                    [AllowOnlyNumbers]=true
                    [maxLength]= 'yearlyFieldMaxLength'
                    type="tel"
                    name="totalAnnualIncome"
                    formControlName="totalAnnualIncome"
                    [(ngModel)]="yearlyIncomeAmt"
                    (focus)="onFocusEnableToolTip('TotalAnnualIncome')" 
                    (focusout)="onFocusOutDisableToolTip('TotalAnnualIncome')" 
                     minlength="2"
                     autocomplete="off"/>
```

A very simple directive restricts users to put only numbers in the textbox.

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[AllowOnlyNumbers]'
})

/**
 * @method AllowOnlyNumbers
 * @desc This directive restricts the keyboard entry to numbers only.
 * Users can enter numbers and can use backspace, tab,enter, escape, end, home, left, right and del keys.
 * Usage: <input type = "text" [AllowOnlyNumbers] = true />
 */

export class AllowOnlyNumbers {

  constructor() { }

  @Input() AllowOnlyNumbers: boolean;
  /**
   * @methodspace AllowOnlyNumbers
   * @method onKeyDown
   * @desc It restricts the keyboard entry to numbers only.
   * @argument event
   * @returns returns only digit
   *
   */
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {
    const e = event as KeyboardEvent;
    if (this.AllowOnlyNumbers) {
      // Allow: 8=Backspace, 9= Tab, 13=CR, 27=ESC, 35=END, 36=HOME, 37=Left, 39=Right, 46=DEL
      if ([8, 9, 13, 27, 35, 36, 37, 39, 46].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1) {
        return;
      }

      // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
      if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, when writing the Unit test case using jasmine, I am not able to set the `@Input() AllowOnlyNumbers` property as true. This is always undefined. 
Below is my UT file. (Note: Keydown event is getting fired)

```
import {ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AllowOnlyNumbers } from './allow-only-numbers.directive';
import { Component, DebugElement, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  template: `<input [AllowOnlyNumbers]= true type="text" name="totalAnnualIncome"  />`
})
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-unnecessary-class
class TestAllowOnlyNumbersComponent {
 //  allowNumbers = true;
}
fdescribe('Directive: AllowOnlyNumbers', () => {
  let component: TestAllowOnlyNumbersComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestAllowOnlyNumbersComponent>;
  let inputEl: DebugElement;
  let linkDes;
  let routerLinks;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestAllowOnlyNumbersComponent, AllowOnlyNumbers],
      schemas:      [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestAllowOnlyNumbersComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    inputEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[name="totalAnnualIncome"]'));
  });

  it('keydown input', () => {
    inputEl.triggerEventHandler('keydown', {});
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });

});
```

I am using [this link](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/directives/) as reference. I am not able to set the `@Input() AllowOnlyNumbers` property as true. This is always undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Answer to your issue:**

It should be `[AllowOnlyNumbers]="true"` not `[AllowOnlyNumbers]= true` in `TestAllowOnlyNumbersComponent`.

What you're actually doing is `[AllowOnlyNumbers]=` which does not assign any value to the input of directive.

Also you should move `fixture.detectChanges()` before the `triggerEventHandler` to trigger initial value binding or even better would be to add it at the end of the `beforeEach`

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    ...
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('keydown input', () => {
    inputEl.triggerEventHandler('keydown', {});
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
```

**Also additional comment about your directive:**

I think you should replace `keyCode` with `key` in your directive, as it looks like `keyCode` is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent.
I think change should be easy, in your directive you just read that key string and a code based on that value `const code = e.key.charCodeAt()`

Then I'd create following test, to test one of the keys in this case 'F' key:

```
  it('keydown input', () => {
    const event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'F' });
    inputEl.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
    expect(event.defaultPrevented).toBe(true);
  });
```

I guess that might work when making that change in the directive.

Comment: Right, you should also add `fixture.detectChanges();` before the `triggerEventHandler` which should trigger initial value binding, I think that should work.

Comment: yes, moving fixture.detectChanges() up, worked for me, Can you please modify your answer, so that I can approve it.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Done, happy I helped :)

Comment: Can you please tell, What can I write to be expected instead of `expect(true).toBe(true);`

Comment: I've updated my answer with suggested changes and test